# Trapezoidal rule in 2 dimensions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I'm using trying to integrate a function in MATLAB using the trapezoidal rule. I'm struggling to get the limits right and how to set up the steps.

The limits for $x$ are $[0,2]$ and the limits for $y$ are $[0,\sin(\frac{x \times \pi}{2})]$.

The thing I'm struggling with is how to set up the steps in the inner integral when the upper limit depends on $x$. My professor said the the length of the steps in each of the directions should be roughly equal and that the number of steps needed are going to vary with $x$.

The function is a smooth function and will be called from a different file. Im trying to use $2$ for-loops to make all this happen.

Any suggestion on how to do this? Examples would be even better!

Answer (score 1):

You got to evaluate
$$
I=\int_0^2 h(x)\,dx\quad\text{with}\quad h(x)=\int_0^{r(x)}f(x,y)\,dy\,.
$$
The numerical integration for $h(x)$ can be totally independent from that of $I$. The error in the integration for $h(x)$ is $O(r(x)·(Δy)^2)$. To get an error level proportional to $(Δx)^2$, use $Δy=Δx/\sqrt{r(x)/r_{max}}$. This makes about $$r(x)/Δy=\sqrt{r(x)/r_{max}}·r(x)/Δx$$ sub-intervals in the $y$-direction.